# How to display '%' with only one decimal

Tags: visualforce

I have an outputText where I display value from a controller.
This is what I am currently using:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,###.0}"> 
  <apex:param value="{!IF(ISNUMBER(test__c),test__c,'')}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

If at all there a value in `test__c`, that value is displayed.
For Example: if value is 12.432 then its is shown as 12.4

This works well for me.
But now how can I add a **suffix %** to the outputText? i.e. I need the value as 12.4%

Answer (score 7):

The % character is supported as part of the outputText format.

You can use syntax like this to achieve the formatting you want

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###.0%}">
    <apex:param value=".....your value here...."/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this -

```
apex:outputText value="{0,number,###.0}">
      <apex:param value="{!test_c}" />
<apex:outputText>%
```

suffix % at the end of `<apex:outputText>` tag.

Comment: If i do that the value is now showing as 12.40% i.e., having two decimal places

Comment: i think my problem will be solved if there is way to add % in the apex:param tag. something like test__c+%.

Comment: yes i want only one digit after decimal point along with the suffix

Comment: no test__c+% would give Syntax error. Are you using any javascript for calculations?

Comment: i have no javascript running as of now. the value is directly from controller

Comment: your format is correct. it should only display single digit after decimal point. Can you send me your page and controller code so that i can help you. will have to see your code

Comment: Actually i am using this in a pageblock table, in which a list is iterated. the list contains values of some fields from test__C object:   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="acc" id="accId" border="1">
                
  <apex:column >
   <apex:facet name="header">Value </apex:facet> 
      <apex:outputText value="{0,number,###.0}"> 
       <apex:param value="{!IF(ISNUMBER(TEXT(acc.Value)),acc.Value,'')}"/>
      </apex:outputText>
  </apex:column>
                 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

Comment: where accList is just from a simple query from test__c object

Comment: acc.Value is actually a decimal which has more than 4 decimal places in the backend. though storing its exact value, i wish to show only 1 decimal on VF page

Comment: Just do like this in apex param - <apex:param value="{!acc.Value}"/>

Comment: yes it works but i cant append %

Comment: Do like this - <apex:outputText value="{0,number,###.0}">
      <apex:param value="{!acc.Value}"/>
<apex:outputText>%

Comment: its still showing 2 decimal places

Comment: are you still using ISNUMBER method under apex:param?

Comment: no i have removed it and tried

Comment: it shows two decimals if i append %. if i dont append it and use the format, it shows 1 decimal

Comment: something is wrong at your end. just appending % would not convert your number from 1 to 2 digit

Answer (score 0):

Within the curly braces the apex executions parts are located. so you just need avoid the execution section in simply within the quote but out side the curly brackets would do the trick for you.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###.0}%">
    <apex:param value=".....your value here...."/>
</apex:outputText>
```